# Missed "processing' panel in QGIS 2.12.2 Lyon

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have missing 'processing' panel in my QGIS Lyon version. It happened once some time ago, so I re-installed program then. And now I have the same situation -  I've cleaned my QGIS registry key and nothing changed. Anyone have any idea why? And how I can bring it back without re-installing?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @user71957! Did you enable the Processing plugin from the toolbar: _Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins..._?